# Observe div mutation via ajax request

Tags: javascript

Consider the following simple structure

```
<button type="button">Click</button>
<div class="content"></div>
```

When the button is clicked, it triggers an AJAX request which populates `.content` with other divs. Is it possible to observe when `.content` gets populated and react to it ?

This is what I've tried, but it doesnt seem to trigger the callback function.

```
  var target_node = document.querySelector('.content');

  const observer = new MutationObserver(function(){
    console.log('changed');
  })

  observer.observe(target_node, {childList: true, subtree: true});
```

Answer (score 2):

Your code is working.

Below is a working snippet

```js
var target_node = document.querySelector('.content');

  const observer = new MutationObserver(function(){
    console.log('changed');
  })

  observer.observe(target_node, {childList: true, subtree: true});
  
  function populate() {
    document.querySelector('.content').innerHTML = Math.random()
  }
```

```html
<button type="button" onclick="populate()">Click</button>
<div class="content"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Where are you setting that code? Might be that the target_node is null?

This code works:

```
<html>
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function populateContent() {
            document.getElementById('content').innerHTML = 'content!';
            document.getElementById('content')
        }
        function setObserver() {
                    const target_node = document.querySelector('.content');

          const observer = new MutationObserver(function(){
            console.log('changed');
          })

          observer.observe(target_node, {childList: true, subtree: true});
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body onload="setObserver()">
<button type="button" onclick="populateContent()">Click</button>
    <div id="content" class="content"></div>
</body>
```